# Entity Framework Core 2.0 Scaffold-DbContext returns Build Error

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

In Visual Studio 2017, create a .NET core class library project with Target Framework as 2.0.

Have included below packages by Package Manager console.

1. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design
3. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
4. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design

While running below Scaffold-DbContext command from Package Manager console of the same project, getting Build Failed error.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=HTGHTFG135611L;Initial Catalog=HHH;Persist Security Info=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir DBModels -force -v
```

Also tried giving UserId and password, still the same error.

Comment: add your error please

Comment: PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=XXXXXXXX;Initial Catalog=HHH;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXXX;Password=XXXXX" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir DBModels -force -v -Tables Address,Household,Person,PersonRelationship,RelationshipType 
Using project 'HHH.DataModel'.
Using startup project 'HHH.DataModel'.
Build started...
Build failed.

Comment: Also tried from windows power shell , below are the details :

Comment: Scaffold-DbContext : The term 'Scaffold-DbContext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.

Comment: Do you get any errors manually building the project? (Ctrl+Shift+B)

Comment: No i am not getting build errors when running the project

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem today, please be sure **any project in your solution** does not fail to build. Examine output folder after you got this error. I think one of your projects in your solution fails to build.

Comment: Ya that right , there is another project in the solution which has build errors. When i have unloaded the project and rerun the command its working.   Oppps.......

Comment: Then can you please select this answer as correct... :)

Comment: Just further to this, you need to set the project you are scaffolding as the start up object.

Comment: And if your scaffolding has become corrupted? and you now have tons of code (that won't  build,) reliant on that scaffold? what then? Catch 22. Punt?